# Python + Selenium to submit query on webpage

Tags: python, selenium

Hello all…I am trying to use Python and Selenium to submit query, a pair of coordinates “40.67243, -74.08379” on Google Map.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://maps.google.com/')
driver.find_element_by_id("searchboxinput").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("searchboxinput").send_keys("40.67243, -74.08379")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.searchbutton").click()
```

using above returns chunk of error message and problem starts from:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("searchboxinput").clear()
```

when I check it from Chrome, and seems there’s no an element “searchboxinput”. Is it the reason?

What’s the way to submit query? Thanks.

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Gmap.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("searchboxinput").clear()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 197, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 681, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'{"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id \'searchboxinput\'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"95","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:62738","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\\"using\\": \\"id\\", \\"sessionId\\": \\"e6a0af20-4f91-11e4-a8b7-7b4551650c5b\\", \\"value\\": \\"searchboxinput\\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/e6a0af20-4f91-11e4-a8b7-7b4551650c5b/element"}}' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

Comment: I've just opened google maps and the element for the search box does have `id="searchboxinput"`. What exception or error are you seeing?

Comment: thanks, Mark Rowlands. I added the error message.

Comment: First thing I notice is that opening the page in Firefox and Chrome gives two differently rendered pages - Chrome gives us the `id=searchboxinput` whereas Firefox gives us an input with `name=q`. I have never used PhantomJS but if it falls under the "isn't Chrome so do other" style, try with `driver.find_element_by_name("q")`

Comment: @MarkRowlands, I have checked the URL using Firefox; there IS an element with 'id=searchboxinput'.

Comment: thanks for the comment, Mark Rowlands. "q" doesn't work neither...

Comment: Just did some more investigation, opened the page with PhantomJS, wrote the page source to a file and opened it so I could see what it 'looks like' in Phantomjs and for me, at least, the search box element is: `<input id="gbqfq" class="gbqfif" name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off" value x-webkit speech x-webkit-grammar=builtin:maps">`

Answer (score 0):

Everithing seems fine. Exception says that there is no element with id searchboxinput. So maybe you confused id with class or something like that?

Comment: I think you should post a comment instead.